# The need to resolve query issues

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT fname, sname, email 
FROM student WHERE contact_flag='Yes' AND sno!='$lastid'
```

How can I re-write this query in such a way that it doesn't select data that are linked to the $lastid and thereby retrieving the others? Have been struggling with this for quite some time now and I can't figure it out. Help me please!

Comment: So that it **doesn't not select** data linked to $lastid?

Comment: What is your question, how not linked to $lastid, i dont get it. Also if this is homework, tag it as homework

Comment: Either you want lastid: `WHERE contact_flag='Yes' AND sno ='$lastid'`, or NOT lastid `WHERE contact_flag='Yes' AND sno!='$lastid'` or you want everything: `WHERE contact_flag='Yes';`

Comment: sorry just edited it... I need the query to select from the database but to ignore only the $lastid records

Answer (score 0):

try this, totally untested

```
SELECT fname, sname, email 
FROM student WHERE contact_flag='Yes' AND sno NOT IN (SELECT sno FROM student WHERE sno='$lastid')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using php variable inside single quote. Try "$lastid". Hope this will help.